# Retrieve unique lists of a specific field from a list of records

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

```
 class Class1
    {

        private bool _noise = false;
        private bool _cmbGrammageSelected = false;
        private bool _cmbSize1Selected = false;
        private bool _cmbSize2Selected = false;

        private static refine()
```

The Section below was my trying to refactor, but I did not want to convert the other 2 sections as I feel it is still very messy.

```
 List<string> Size1s = GetSize1sFrom(Finallist);               
                string oldSize1Value = cmbSize1.Text;
                Size1s = InsertBlankValue(Size1s);
                DisableComboBoxEventHandler();                      
                if (_cmbSize1Selected == false) { cmbSize1.DataSource = Size1s; }
                cmbSize1.Text = oldSize1Value;
                EnableComboboxEventHandler();
```

This is the other 2 sections...

```
            List<string> Size2s = new List<string>();
                Size2s = Finallist.Select(x => x.Size2.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();                
                string oldSize2Value = cmbSize2.Text;
                Size2s.Insert(0,"");
                _noise = true; // cause the handler to ignore the noise...    
                if (_cmbSize2Selected == false) { cmbSize2.DataSource = Size2s; }
                cmbSize2.Text = oldSize2Value;
                _noise = false;  // let the event process again

                List<string> Grammages = new List<string>();
                Grammages = Finallist.Select(x => x.Grammage.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();               
                string oldGrammageValue = cmbGrammage.Text;
                Grammages.Insert(0,"");
                _noise = true; // cause the handler to ignore the noise...
            if(_cmbGrammageSelected == false){cmbGrammage.DataSource = Grammages;}
                cmbGrammage.Text = oldGrammageValue;
                _noise = false;  // let the event process again
            //////////////////
```

This Runs after the other sections are complete...

```
 SetComboboxsSelectedFlagToFalse();
```

And here is the functions called from the first section...

```
 }

        private static List<string> GetSize1sFrom(List<Stock_Paper_Record> Finallist)
        {
            List<string> Size1s = new List<string>();

            Size1s = Finallist.Select(x => x.Size1.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
            return Size1s;
        }

        private void SetComboboxsSelectedFlagToFalse()
        {
            _cmbGrammageSelected = false;
            _cmbSize1Selected = false;
            _cmbSize2Selected = false;
        }

        private void EnableComboboxEventHandler()
        {
            _noise = false;
        }

        private void DisableComboBoxEventHandler()
        {
            _noise = true;
        }

        private static List<string> InsertBlankValue(List<string> l)
        {
            l.Insert(0, "");
            return l;
        }
    }
```

I feel this code is Messy and there is lots of repeat code. I would also like to make use of design patterns but I do not know which one to use. Even a point in the right direction of design patterns would be a great start.  Just find I pick what I think is the right one then end up being unsure.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Comment: I have changed the Tile to be more descriptive, thanks for you input.

Comment: Try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your specific question on design patterns I don't have any immediate advice.  However a few formatting and standard practice stuff does stand out to me.

1. Using "white space" to help with readability

   When scanning code, if a whole bunch of lines are grouped together without spaces between it can sometimes make it harder to read.  So in general I try to put some white
   space around logical parts, and especially if I'm using braces.  So:

   ```
   if (_cmbSize2Selected == false) { cmbSize2.DataSource = Size2s; }
   ```

   would become

   ```
   if (_cmbSize2Selected == false) 
   { 
       cmbSize2.DataSource = Size2s; 
   }
   ```
2. Using var to reduce noise as well as initialization on same line

   ```
   var Size2s = Finallist.Select(x => x.Size2.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
   ```
3. Using correct casing for variable naming (in this case manually camelCase)

   It's standard practice in c# to use camelCase for variable naming within methods.  So

   ```
   List<string> Size2s = new List<string>();
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   List<string> size2s = new List<string>();
   ```
4. Making use of built in functionality

   In .NET (and most languages I guess) you do not have to explicity compare a variable to it's boolean representation.  So in .NET you could change this line

   ```
   if (_cmbSize2Selected == false) { cmbSize2.DataSource = Size2s; }
   ```

   would become

   ```
   if (!_cmbSize2Selected) 
   { 
      cmbSize2.DataSource = size2s; 
   }
   ```
5. Yes I agree that there is some duplicated code that could be refactored into methods.  However that might be for another post.

A full attempt at refactoring based on the suggestions above shows:

```
var size2s = Finallist.Select(x => x.Size2.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
size2s.Insert(0,"");

string oldSize2Value = cmbSize2.Text;

_noise = true; // cause the handler to ignore the noise...    
if (!_cmbSize2Selected) 
{ 
    cmbSize2.DataSource = Size2s; 
}

cmbSize2.Text = oldSize2Value;
_noise = false;  // let the event process again

var grammages = Finallist.Select(x => x.Grammage.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();               
string oldGrammageValue = cmbGrammage.Text;
grammages.Insert(0,"");

_noise = true; // cause the handler to ignore the noise...
if(!_cmbGrammageSelected)
{
    cmbGrammage.DataSource = grammages;
}

cmbGrammage.Text = oldGrammageValue;
_noise = false;  // let the event process again
```

Comment: Thanks did not know this if (!_cmbSize2Selected) my code will read better now :)